An Interesting theoretical graph theory problem
My dad recently introduced me to a difficult problem he is trying to solve. The original problem arose while trying to find the optimal way to perform certain sql operations. I will be rephrasing the problem to make it far more concise and because I’m only interested in the theoretical algorithm and not the particular implementation.
Here is my colorful recreation of the problem:
You need to make everyone like you. You can make a targeted person like you by bribing them directly or sometimes by bribing a specific group of people, who already like you, to convince the target to like you.
Given the total number of people N, and a list L of K bribing options find out the cheapest way to make everyone like you.
Each bribing option shall either contain

Two numbers with the first number representing the person to bribe into liking you and the second number representing the cost of the bribe.
A list of numbers representing the group of people to bribe, a number representing the person to convince to like you, and a final number representing the total cost of the bribe. In order to perform a group bribe, you must of already made every individual in that group like you.

Here is an example:
People: 3
Options:

1, 10 (you can bribe person 1 to like you for a cost of 10)
1, 2, 5 (you can bribe person 1 to make person 2 like you for a cost of 5)
2, 7 (you can bribe person 2 to like you for a cost of 7)
1, 2, 3, 3 (you can bribe person 1 and 2 to make person 3 like you for a cost of 3)

In this example the optimal solution is to use the first, second, and fourth options to make everyone like you for a total cost of 18.
Can y’all help me find a generalized algorithm that will work for any case?
There aren’t concrete number limits, but I can say that the number of people is almost always going to be small (< 10) and the number of bribing options could be very large (N * (2^(N-1))).

Related: this is somewhat similar to CCO 2017 Problem 5.

See graph coloring

@nate Can you share the related SQL question/interpretation?

@user24714692 How would you use graph coloring to solve this?

@Dave Consider each person as a vertex in a graph. Each bribe as an edge connecting the person being bribed and the person doing the bribing. Then, you can use graph coloring algorithms to find the minimum cost "to make everyone like you", where each color represents a group of people "who like each other" and the cost represents the total cost of bribing them.

@user24714692 How do you handle bribes to groups, as in the OP's last example ('you can bribe person 1 and 2 to make person 3 like you for a cost of 3)'? Even with this handled, how does coloring get you a solution? If you have a solution, please post it.

@Dave Can't we "color" person 1 to like you for a cost of X? Isn't this therefore a graph coloring problem? If you say it's not, maybe it's not.  ( ˆ_ˆ )

It is worth pointing out that this problem is NP hard. Proof. Take a graph G. Make the cost of bribing any node be 1 if you've already bribed all nodes that have edges to this one, and 10 on its own. Then solving this problem will solve https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feedback_vertex_set, whose minimization problem is NP hard.

Since n (number of people) is small, an approach inefficient in n may be okay.
Let's think of the digraph like this. Each node is a state, where each of the n people is either bribed or not bribed. Then, there are 2^n nodes.
Each node gets an arc to each node that is immediately reachable from it, i.e., that consists of the same set of bribed people as the node in question, plus one additional. The weight/cost of each arc is the cheapest cost of going between the nodes.
Once the weights are assigned, it's a matter of using your favorite algorithm to find the shortest-path in a DAG with (presumably) nonnegative weights. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem
So how do we assign those weights? Here's one approach:
First, give each node an id where the i'th bit is set if the i'th person is bribed. So the initial state node gets an id of 0, its children get ids that have 1 bit set, and so on.
Next, associate the id that goes to each group that can be used for a bribe with the cost & id of the person to be bribed. Since one group can be used to bribe multiple people, represent this as a map {person_to_bribe => cost}.
Next, parse all nodes in order of their distance from node 0. Each nodes map gets created/updated based on its predecessors, with the cost to each node being the min of its and its predecessors maps. Once this is done for depth i, assign the appropriate weight to the arcs out of each depth i node, based on the updated map.
This is not efficient, but since n < 10 this should be fine.
nodes: 2^n <= 2^9 = 512
arcs: choose(n,0) * choose(n,1) + choose(n,1) + choose(n,2) + ... + choose(n,n-1) * choose(n,n) <= 43,758 (equals this for n=9)


Should explicitly mention uniform cost search, I think.

@MattTimmermans I'm likely missing something; why UCS over other options?

It's the way to do what you wrote without instantiating all the graph edges.
